# Turn an byte encoded Key back into it's original ECPublicKey in Bouncy Castle

Tags: java, encryption, bouncycastle, elliptic-curve

In Java I have a ECDH public Key that I am sending as a byte array.

Once I have received the byte array how can I turn it back into a public key?

I am using Bouncy Castle but a Java solution would be just as useful.

Thanks

Comment: What is the class you are using to represent your Java ECDH public key? You get better answers by showing your code and not requiring people to guess.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How are the raw bytes formatted for the ECDH key?  Where are you getting the raw bytes?

Generally, one uses the appropriate *Spec class to turn raw key material into a Key but the [ECPublicKeySpec](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/spec/ECPublicKeySpec.html) and [DHPublicKeySpec](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/crypto/spec/DHPublicKeySpec.html) classes don't accept a raw byte array.

Answer (score 7):

When you got the encoded key, assuming you used the default "[your keyPair].getPublic().getEncoded()" method, this will work.

```
    X509EncodedKeySpec ks = new X509EncodedKeySpec(pubKeyByteString.toByteArray());
    KeyFactory kf;
    try {
         kf = java.security.KeyFactory.getInstance("ECDH");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        log.error("Cryptography error: could not initialize ECDH keyfactory!", e);
        return;
    }

    ECPublicKey remotePublicKey;

    try {
        remotePublicKey = (ECPublicKey)kf.generatePublic(ks);
    } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        log.warn("Received invalid key specification from client",e);
        return;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        log.warn("Received valid X.509 key from client but it was not EC Public Key material",e);
        return;
    }
```

Comment: I get java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: encoded key spec not recognised

Answer (score 5):

I found the above solution by @LaceCard didn't work for me. In general this isn't obvious but then again nothing in cryptography is ;)

```
String key = "MihU9ztW9sEvkBL6BxyaOMgkSbodNS8yoHaHcio+WE...blahblah"
byte[] keyBytes = Base64.decode(key);

//If using Android and Spongycastle provider should be "SC"
KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("ECDH", "BC");
//CURVE_NAME e.g prime192v1
ECParameterSpec ecSpec = ECNamedCurveTable.getParameterSpec(CURVE_NAME);
ECPoint point = ecSpec.getCurve().decodePoint(keyBytes);
ECPublicKeySpec pubSpec = new ECPublicKeySpec(point, ecSpec);

ECPublicKey myECPublicKey = (ECPublicKey) kf.generatePublic(pubSpec);
```

Note: you'll need to handle the potential exceptions appropriately